# Django Tempus Dominus TimePicker Format

Tags: python, django, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

When I submit a form after picking a time using the django-tempus-dominus TimePicker widget, I receive no error, but the form is not saved to the database, and does not show up in the admin page.  I receive a visual browser indication that something is incorrect with my TimeFields. I can successfully create a new form from the admin page, and only see the issue when submitting from my form page.  I'm not sure whether this is an issue with the 'format' of the TimePicker widget in my forms.py, an issue with my TIME_INPUT_FORMATS in my settings.py, or something else.

If I use a DateTimeField with a DateTimePicker widget for start_time and end_time, and change the 'format' in my widget to 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm: A', instead of using a TimeField with a TimePicker widget, the form works correctly, and when submitted, can be viewed from the admin page.

In my settings.py:

```py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Kentucky/Monticello'

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y/%m/%d %I:%M %p', ]

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y/%m/%d', ]

TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%I:%M %p', ]

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True
```

In my models.py:

```py
start_time = models.TimeField(
        verbose_name="Start Time", help_text="Time the issue first occurred.")
```

In my forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from tempus_dominus.widgets import DatePicker, TimePicker

from .models import DMDCTracker


class DMDCTrackerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DMDCTracker
        fields = ["date_issue_occurred", "start_time", "end_time", "number_of_csrs", "agents_affected", "ticket_number", "workstation_id",
                  "issue_location", "vpn_name", "server_name", "issue_category", "issue_description"]
        widgets = {
            'date_issue_occurred': DatePicker(
                options={
                    'format': 'YYYY/MM/DD',
                },
                attrs={
                    'append': 'fa fa-calendar',
                    'icon_toggle': True,
                },
            ),
            'start_time': TimePicker(
                options={
                    'format': 'hh:mm A'
                },
                attrs={
                    'append': 'fa fa-clock-o',
                    'icon_toggle': True,
                },
            ),
            'end_time': TimePicker(
                options={
                    'format': 'hh:mm A'
                },
                attrs={
                    'append': 'fa fa-clock-o',
                    'icon_toggle': True,
                },
            ),
        }
```

In my tracker_form.html:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST" action="." class="tracker-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="mt-2 text-center">Track a New Issue</h2>
        <hr class="mt-0 mb-4">
        {{ form.date_issue_occurred|as_crispy_field }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                {{ form.start_time|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                {{ form.end_time|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Screenshot of the visual indication in the browser:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/giaF6.jpg

Comment: Are there any errors on the front end?

Comment: I don't receive any errors on the front end.

Comment: Have you tried setting `TEMPUS_DOMINUS_LOCALIZE` to true? `get_js_format` from `class TimePicker(TempusDominusMixin, forms.widgets.TimeInput)` uses that constant.

Comment: I just tried it, but I still have the same issue.